# Selenium WebDriver not responding during redirect

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to access a website using selenium chromedriver. The website redirects to try and authenticate with a pop up for single sign on (SSO) before redirecting back to the original site. I'm unable to pass in any commands to the webdriver after I go to the website and have been redirected to the SSO pop up.

I've tried to refresh the browser, navigate to different pages in a try/catch and they have all failed. I've already tried updating my chromedriver and passing in authentication credentials via the URL to no avail.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57718/session/27f1542adf870ebc059a2a23b1061060/refresh timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.Refresh()
```

This is the error message for all subsequent commands that I try and pass into the webdriver.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So once your browser launches a popup then you want to switch event to switch between popup and originally launched browser. you can use index number for it to achieve this using command shown below. Once switched to the required window you can perform required operations in regular way.

```
var newDriver = driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[Windowindex]); //give index as 1 or 2 as required for your case. and use newdriver to perform actions and events
```

Hope this help. Let me know if any clarification required.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. Commands to the webdriver are still timing out while it's waiting for the page to load.

Comment: can you please mention exact exception so that i can help better